# How to add git version information for Fortran project in Visual studio pre-build event

Tags: git, visual-studio, batch-file

I am trying to add pre-build event to add version information for my Fortran project on Windows. The pre-build event is to create gitparams.h file and then write some git information into it. I have no problem writing the file using following the command line and use it in Version.F90 file.

Pre-build command:

```cmd
echo | set /p dummyName=#define GITVERSION > gitparams.h
git describe --dirty --always --tags >> gitparams.h

echo | set /p dummyName=#define GITBRANCH >> gitparams.h
git branch --show-current >> gitparams.h
```

Output in `gitparams.h`:

```fortran
#define GITVERSION 61154c3-dirty
#define GITBRANCH main
```

In `Version.F90` file:

```fortran
#include "gitparams.h"

#if defined(GITVERSION)
    Character(32) :: GlobalRevisionNumber = GITVERSION
#else
    Character(32) :: GlobalRevisionNumber = "unknown"
#endif
```

Error:

```text
error #5143: Missing mandatory separating blankSyntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'C3' when expecting one of: :: ) , : \* \<END-OF-STATEMENT\> ; . (/ + - \] /) ' \*\* / // \> PRIVATE ...
```

One solution is to add quotation mark in `gitparams.h` for those value with specific characters or numbers, as shown below:

```fortran
#define GITVERSION "61154c3-dirty"
#define GITBRANCH "main"
```

However, I tried several method but failed to get what I want. I am not familiar with bash script. Would anyone help to give me some advice or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing [*`batch`*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) with [*`bash`*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)).

**Edit:** I didn't realize it was a Visual Studio pre-build command. If you're not running it as a batch script then you may need to change `%%i` to `%i` in the `for` commands.

The following `batch` script is not pretty but it should work. You'll want to name it something like `gitparams.bat` and run it using command prompt like `start gitparams.bat`.

```
@echo off

: get the version into gitversion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('git describe --dirty --always --tags') do set gitversion=%%i

: get the branch into gitbranch
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('git branch --show-current') do set gitbranch=%%i

(
  echo | set /p dummyName=#define GITVERSION "%gitversion%"
  echo:
  echo | set /p dummyName=#define GITBRANCH "%gitbranch%"
) > gitparams.h

@echo on
```

The contents of `gitparams.h` should then resemble:

```
#define GITVERSION "61154c3-dirty"
#define GITBRANCH "main"
```

I didn't have a git repo with tags handy so there may be some more troubleshooting involved, just let me know.

Comment: Thanks Jonny for your quick reply. Your suggestions works fine. One more question about git commit time.
```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('git log -1 --format=%cd --date=format-local:"%Y-%m-%dT%T%z"') do set gitcommittime=%%i
```
The above line does not work, Error:| was unexpected at this time. This command works fine in powershell, but not in batch file. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the error is stemming from the use of `%` in the date format string, batch/DOS uses `%` as variable identifiers (and maybe some other stuff). Let me look into it and I'll edit my answer with a hopeful fix.

Comment: Thanks Jonny. I updated the post to include the two solutions from you and Compo.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a fixed version of the recent edit of your new code:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Rem Define variable for the location of git executable
Set "git=P:\athTo\git.exe"

Rem Undefine possible existing variables used later
For %%G In (repurl branch version committime) Do Set "git%%G="

Rem Get the repository URL into GITREPURL
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('^""%git%" config --get remote.origin.url 2^>NUL^"') Do Set "gitrepurl=%%G"

Rem Get the branch into GITBRANCH
For /F "delims=" %%G In ('^""%git%" branch --show-current 2^>NUL^"') Do Set "gitbranch=%%G"

Rem Get the version into GITVERSION
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('^""%git%" describe --dirty --always --tags 2^>NUL^"') Do Set "gitversion=%%G"

Rem Get the commit time into GITCOMMITTIME
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('^""%git%" log -1 --format^=%%cd --date^=format-local:"%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%T%%z" 2^>NUL^"') Do Set "gitcommittime=%%G"

Rem End script if any of the previous variable definitions failed
For %%G In (repurl branch version committime) Do If Not Defined git%%G GoTo :EOF

Define variables for the date and time
Set "_d=%DATE%"
Set "_t=%TIME%"

Rem Create the header file
(
    Echo #define GITREPURL "%gitrepurl%"
    Echo #define GITBRANCH "%gitbranch%"
    Echo #define GITVERSION "%gitversion%"
    Echo #define GITCOMMITTIME "%gitcommittime%"
    Echo #define BUILDTIME "%_d%T%_t:~0,2%:%_t:~3,2%:%_t:~6,2%"
) 1>"GitParams.h"

EndLocal
```

*Please remember to change `P:\athTo`, on line five, to the actual location of your git executable.*

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I already changed the path of git and there is no space in the path. Git related output is empty. The build time line works fine. BTW: Added Rem before Define line to comment this line.
#define GITREPURL ""
#define GITBRANCH ""
#define GITVERSION ""
#define GITCOMMITTIME ""
#define BUILDTIME "2024-03-04T20:38:26"

Comment: I get #define BUILDTIME "2024-03-04T20:38:26" in line five, which is right. I need to comment the lines before 'Define variables for the date and time', otherwise, the batch file does not run, no 'GitParams.h' was generated. And there is no error information printed. Tested on Windows 11.

Comment: line five `Set "git=R:\Git\bin\git.exe"`

Comment: @JonnyHenly, thanks for your help. You copied the comments correctly. I deleted the comments here to make the post easier to follow.

Comment: @DanielSu `For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('^""%git%" log -1 --format^=%%cd --date^=format-local:"%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%M:%%S%%z" 2^>NUL^"') Do Set "gitcommittime=%%G"`

Comment: I corrected my code above, after I had time to fully analyse the output @JonnyHenly. You may remove your comments now. You will note however that `GITREPURL`, `GITBRANCH` and `GITVERSION` lines all worked correctly pre-fix despite the OP stating otherwise.

Comment: @Compo I believe git uses `strftime` for date format parsing, is it just my machine's `strftime` that doesn't recognize the `%T` specifier? Does `git log -1 --format=%cd --date=format-local:"%Y-%m-%dT%T%z"` work on your machine? -- Also, thank you for writing your answer, I +1'ed it. I tend to lose hours when it comes to debugging/troubleshooting batch scripts.

Comment: I can confirm @JonnyHenly your suggestion works. Thank you both.
`For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('^""%git%" log -1 --format^=%%cd --date^=format-local:"%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%M:%%S%%z" 2^>NUL^"') Do Set "gitcommittime=%%G"`